# can't log in after creating a new user with passport & passport-local

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, mongoose-schema, passport-local

I am using express and I can't seem to log in once I create a new user. I check the database. The username is registered. But nothing happens when I try to log in to the account. It keeps re-directing me to the login page. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

My user Model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

// var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
//     username: String,
//     password: String,
//     email: String,
//     firstName: String,
//     lastName: String,
//     motive: String,
//     level: {type: Number, default: 0}
// });

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

My passport config:

```
app.use(require("express-session")({
  secret: "lena paul is the best",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //save data submitted from form to req.body
```

Registration logic:

```
//handles registration logic
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
  var newUser = new User({
    username:req.body.username
    // firstName:req.body.firstName,
    // lastName:req.body.lastName,
    // email:req.body.email,
    // motive:req.body.motive
  });
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, newUser){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.render("register");
    }
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
      res.redirect("/login");
    });
  });
});
```

Log in logic:

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local",
  {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
  }), function(req, res){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

The problem was in the POST log in form. I didn't have a "name" for the field.